# Bootstrap navbar refresh on tab change

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap's navbar. The content of each tab comes from a php function which loads data from the database. Once the page has loaded I'd like to be able to refresh the data under each tab (which is equal to calling the respective php functions again) on tab change. I guess that would be the jquery onclick() event but how do I update the content?

```
<?php 
    require_once 'Offers.php';
    $offers = new Offers();
?>

<div class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav" id="mytab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


 <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
       <?php echo($offers->retrieveA());?>   
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
       <?php echo($offers->retrieveB());?>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
       <?php echo($offers->retrieveC());?>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why my question got downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a very simple solution using ajax.

First we attach a jquery event click to each tab, and then fire an ajax call to our functions. Because usually ajax event calls some php script in a file and here we have to deal with functions, we put them in a separate php file and choose between them using a `switch case` statement.

So here we go. First we add ids to navbar tabs:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" id="nav1">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" id="nav2">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" id="nav3">C</a></li>
```

Then click event handlers for each tab. Each handler uses ajax to update tab content.

```
//Functions to dynamically update navbar
$('#nav1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'refreshTabContent.php',
           data: {whichTab: 'tab1'},
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output) {
                     $('#tab1').html(output);
                    }
    });
});
$('#nav2').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'refreshTabContent.php',
           data: {whichTab: 'tab2'},
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output) {
                      $('#tab2').html(output);
                    }
    });
});
$('#nav3').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'refreshTabContent.php',
           data: {whichTab: 'tab3'},
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output) {
                      $('#tab3').html(output);
                    }
    });
});
```

Here's how. In each handler we call the new php script 'refreshTabContent.php' which we're just about to compose. In that script based on the value of `whichTab` we call the appropriate function that returns the content we want to display in the appropriate tab and then echo it back.

```
<?php

require_once 'Offers.php';
$offers = new Offers();


if(isset($_POST['whichTab']) && !empty($_POST['whichTab'])) {
    $action = $_POST['whichTab'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'tab1' : 
            echo($offers->retrieveA());
            break;
        case 'tab2' : 
            echo($offers->retrieveB());
            break;
        case 'tab3' : 
            echo($offers->retrieveC());
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can update anything on-the-fly without reloading the entire page is through javascript/jQuery, specifically in your case using ajax.
So you'd have to attach an `onclick` to your tabs that runs an ajax call back to your PHP file. (I don't remember how bootstrap attaches its own `onclick`, so if it's not working at all, that's where I'd check first).

However, I personally would write a second version of your PHP file in a way that it can accept `$_GET` parameters so it can return the content of only the selected tab.
The result is returned through ajax, and you can then send it back into the tab.

Depending on the content you're getting from PHP, this may cause a short loading pause when you click the tab.

I'm not really sure if it is even worth loading the tab content ahead of time if you're going to reload it on clicking the tab, anyway. Hard to say without more details.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to do just that. Was just hoping for a simple, already implemented solution.

Comment: If the content is supposed to change as you click, then it'll have to be something more complex. I've only recently started using jQuery, but I found the ajax function much easier to use than hand-coding it all in javascript, so that's worth checking out for you. [jQuery ajax reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)